# THREE.js: convert one world coordinate unit to screen pixels

Tags: three.js

For example, I have a unit cube. When there is no scaling, I want to get one coordinate unit represented by how many screen pixels.

[image]

When I zoom in, then this one coordinate unit is represented by how many screen pixels?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if i understood your question, but to get any distance between any two THREE vectors you do this:

```
const distanceAB = new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1).sub( new THREE.Vector3(2,2,2) ).length()
```

Your unit cube would have vertices like (-1,-1,-1) and (1,1,1) among others, (or actually 0.5). Either way you need to obtain these values (easier when using `THREE.Geometry` than `BufferGeometry`).

Then you project these vertices

```
const vertexA = new THREE.Vector3() // set this from cube
const vertexB = new THREE.Vector3() 

const screenSpaceVector = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(vertexA.project(myCamera),vertexB.project(myCamera))
```

The result is now in something called NDC which is a cube going from -1 to 1. To normalize it:

```
screenSpaceVector.multiplyScalar(0.5).add(new THREE.Vector3(0.5,0.5,0.5))
```

Finally to figure out how many pixels this is

```
screenSpaceVector.x *= renderer.getSize().width
screenSpaceVector.y *= renderer.getSize().height
screenSpaceVector.z = 0

const pixelLength = screenSpaceVector.length()
```

I think should do the trick

Comment: // To normalize from NDC to 1 to 0
:

screenSpaceVector.x = (screenSpaceVector.x + 1) * 0.5;
screenSpaceVector.y = (1 - screenSpaceVector.y) * 0.5;

Comment: Hm, not sure about that, you shouldn't have to flip y.